# YouTube has a grey exclamation mark

Tags: youtube

So I am trying to watch this one video but whenever I click on it nothing on the page loads and the video just has a grey exclamation mark.

[image: Here is a screenshot of what happens on this one video]

Comment: Have you tried accessing it on a different browser, etc.?  Is it possible the content is blocked in your location?

Comment: i dont know what happened, i have been randomly refreshing the page every 20 minutes or so, and around 1:30 am it worked. don't know why.

Answer (score 9):

**It happens when a video is unavailable for some reason.**

There might be some reasons for it, for example:

<sub>(sources: [1](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/youtube-say-this-video-is-not-available-how-to-fix-it/), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/89xj7a/youtube_grey_circle_with_exclamation_point/))</sub>

- The video was deleted
- It's restricted in some way (blocked by country, device)
- Internet speed
- Video quality
- etc.

If you'll try to access a non-existing YouTube link, such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akxkrdLasda), you'll get the same as in your screenshot:

[image]

Or this kind of error in the old YouTube design:

[image]

Since you managed to access the video after sometime, it could be caused from something about your network, video quality or a temporary restriction that was changed.

Comment: fwiw, the :\ is only available in the old design, so it'll disappear in the future.

Comment: Oh, didn't knew that - I was just getting it yesterday when I wasn't logged in. So I thought there was a difference if you're logged in or not.

Comment: Do you have any source for that, so that I could add it to the answer? Or It's just general knowledge? Thanks!

Comment: It's quite simple to check: Enable dark mode in the new design (the old one doesn't have it) and open a video that doesn't exist, eg. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arieljannai and note that it has the (!) error. Then switch back to the old design either by using Internet explorer, or via URL parameter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?disable_polymer=1&v=arieljannag and note that it has the :\ error.

Comment: Hmm OK, cool - will add